Translation of odd and even functions
Let $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a periodic function of period $L>0$, that is,
\begin{equation}\label{periodicitycondition}
\varphi(x+L)=\varphi(x),\; \forall\; x \in \mathbb{R}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
First, it follows, immediately from \eqref{periodicitycondition} that,
\begin{equation}\label{periodicityconsequence}
\varphi\left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right)=\varphi\left(x-\frac{L}{2}+L\right)=\varphi\left(x+\frac{L }{2}\right).\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Now, let us define the function $\psi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
\psi(x)=\varphi\left(x-\frac{L}{4}\right),\; \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Note that from \eqref{periodicitycondition}, it follows that
$$
\psi(x+L)=\varphi\left(x+L-\frac{L}{4}\right)=\varphi\left(x-\frac{L}{4}+L\right)= \varphi\left(x-\frac{L}{4}\right)=\psi(x),\; \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R},
$$
that is, $\psi$ is also periodic with period $L>0$. Note that, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are defined in whole real line $\mathbb{R}$.
Question $\mathbf{1}$. If $\varphi$ is odd, then $\psi$ is even?
Question $\mathbf{2}$. If $\varphi$ is even, then $\psi$ is odd?
Attempt to answer Question $\mathbf{1}$:
On the one hand, from since $\varphi$ is odd we see that
\begin{equation}\label{oddcondition3}
\psi(-x)=\varphi\left(-x-\frac{L}{4}\right)=-\varphi\left(x+\frac{L}{4}\right),\; \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R}.\tag{3}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, using \eqref{periodicityconsequence} and the fact that $-\tfrac{L}{4}=\tfrac{L}{4}-\tfrac{L}{2}$ , we obtain that
\begin{equation}\label{oddcondition4}
\psi(x)=\varphi\left(x-\frac{L}{4}\right)=\varphi\left(x+\frac{L}{4}-\frac{L}{2}\right )=-\varphi\left(-x-\frac{L}{4}+\frac{L}{2}\right)=-\varphi\left(-x+\frac{L}{4}\right ),\; \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R}.\tag{4}
\end{equation}
Therefore, I cannot conclude that $\psi$ is even. I have a similar problem when I try to answer Question $2$.
Are the answers to Questions $1$ and $2$ affirmative? If so, how can I proceed?

Consider the even function $\varphi (x)=x^2$ on the interval $[-1,1]$ and extend it periodically.

A counterexample to Question 2 is the function $\varphi(x) = \cos(x)+1$, which is even. $L=2π, \psi(x) = \cos(x-\pi/2)+1$, which is not odd. For Question 1, if you consider $\varphi(x) = \sin(x)/(cos(x)+2)$,period is 2$\pi$. It is odd, but then $\psi(x) = \varphi(x-\pi/2)$ is neither or nor even. For instance, consider $\psi(0.1)$, and $\psi(-0.1)$.  Both answers are negative.
